# How can I programmatically close a ComboBox drop down in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In a Windows Form application (VB.NET) I have a combo box and under certain conditions, when the user opens the DropDown list, I want to display a warning message.
All of this works well: In the DropDown event, I check the conditions and if required I display the warning message.
The problem is that when the user clicks on Yes on the warning message, I move to another tab on the main form and the drop down list still shows even though I've moved away from the tab containing the combo box.
I've searched quite a bit and tried to set DroppedDown to False, call OnDropDownClosed, etc but nothing worked.
It seems that when I try to close the drop down list from within the DropDown event, it doesn't work.
Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks for the answers so far. I forgot to mention that I use .NET framework 2.

Comment: OK I found a simple working solution. 
Just before moving to the other tab (by raising a custom event) I change the ConboBox DropDownStyle to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList, and just after I set it back to its original value ComboBoxStyle.DropDown.

Comment: Changing the dropdown style solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that WinForms 'captures' the mouse to the dropdown *after* it has raised the event.  So within your event handler, there is nothing you can do to prevent the dropdown.  What you *can* do though is schedule the mouse to 'uncapture'.

```
    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>comboBox1.Capture=false));
    }
```

In .NET 4, Dispatcher lives in the WindowsBase assembly under the System.Windows.Threading namespace.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me:

```cs
private void comboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.comboBox.DroppedDown = false));
}
```