# ComboBox is not closing after selecting an item (Using Customer Layout Editor)

Tags: vb.net, combobox, properties, controls

I am having problems with the closing of ComboBox when item is selected, the control is still staying opened.

Because I am using custom Layout Editor, I can not fix the issue with assigning events to the control neither coding at all. All that I have as an option are the **properties of the ComboBox** control which are **inherited**  from Visual Studio. (it's the same as redacting a winform screen in VB)

So my question is : What do I have to change from the properties so my ComboBox gets closed after selecting an item?

Comment: Post the code that duplicates the problem for us.

Comment: As I already mentioned "All that I have as an option are the properties of the ComboBox", so simply I am not asking for the CODE that's solving the issue, but the property.

Comment: Is this WinForms?  ASP.net?  What's a custom Layout Editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can force combobox closing.

The question was answered here:

[How can I programmatically close a ComboBox drop down in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680688/how-can-i-programmatically-close-a-combobox-drop-down-in-vb-net)